# Stack Overflow system UML analysis

Tags: support, privileges, high-rep-users

I'm a computer science student, and I have to do an assignment about how Stack Overflow (or related services) internally work, with UML analysis.

Because I don't usually use stackoverflow, I have extracted the biggest part of the analysis from the FAQ and exploring a little, but I don't find how some high-reputation users actions work.

The questions are:

- How do closed questions work? Can the asker select the best answer while the question is closed?
- How are questions deleted? Do they need a number of delete votes for being deleted (like close-reopen question votes)? Or they are deleted instantly when a high-reputation user says so?

Comment: What's a UML analysis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. All closing does is prevent new answers from being posted for the duration of closure. Any existing answers can be interacted with the same as in an open question, up to and including the acceptance of any answer by the question author.
2. Questions are deleted when either the question author chooses to do so, if enough users with at least 10,000 reputation vote while the question is closed, or if a moderator chooses to do so.

   Our [deletion FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean) covers it in better detail, as the question author and 10,000 rep users have some restrictions. Namely, the presence of upvoted answers can block the question author, while the number of upvotes on questions and answers can increase the required number of votes for 10,000 rep users to delete.

For further inquiries, I suggest gandering our [massive community-maintained FAQ post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites). It contains links to various individual features of the site, usually in detail and mostly up-to-date. Specifically for privileges earned over time, you can also check the [privileges page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges), which can be accessed by clicking on your reputation score in the top bar of any site.